# MYSQL looses connection when doing bulk inserts

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've upgraded both my test-server and new production server from php 5.2 to 5.4.7.
In addition in the PHP code I replaced the old ways of connecting to a mysql database to the new way (so instead of mysql_connect() I use mysqli_connect() method. This because the old way will be deprecated from PHP version 4.5 onwards.

Everything seemed to work fine and was well tested - I thought, but I just discovered that when doing bulk individual insert-queries that the mysql connection hangs. This happens both on the test-server as the production server (Centos Linux). So PHP does make connections fine, it's only when doing bulk inserts that the connection is lost halfway or so.

The test server (Windows XP, using XAMPP) gives the error message:

> mysqli_connect():(HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

On the linux machine I get the error message:

> mysqli_connect():(HY000/2003):Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '127.0.0.1'(99)

What I am basically doing is:

> While Loop a query result
>
> {
>
> $query="insert into (a,b,c,d)values(1,2,3,4)";
>
> query_execute($query);
>
> }

I assume the problem lies with the fact that I am performing to many insert; around 100.000 separate inserts. I am not using persistent mysql connections.

I am clueless as to what is causing this (mysql, PHP, the server itself)?

**added**:
the code (simplified) to run/execute queries is something like:

```
//the database connection class 
class database($query)
{    
    public function setup_connection() { 
        $this->link=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
    } 

    public function execute_query($query){
        mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
    }
}

//a regular php page using the class 

$obj_db1=new database($query);

while($obj_db1->loop()) 
{
    $obj_db_insert=new database($query);
}
```

Comment: If query_execute is a custom function, can you edit your question to include the code for that?

Comment: Use persistent connection when you know there will be bulk inserts. Does `TIME_WAIT` effects TCP connections?

Comment: I've just edited the code to explain the way of connecting to the database. Keep in mind this method always worked for years, and it seems strange it suddenly doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your insert code you are not opening a new connection to the database each time.

My guess was right and based on the code you just posted,

Make your class like below:

```
class database

{

public function setup_connection() {...}

public function execute_query($query){...}

public function close_connection(){...}
}
```

And then in the call make it like below :

```
$db = new database();
$db->setup_connection();

//execute your queries as much as you want ...
//loop start
$db->execute_query($query);
//loop end 

// close connection 
$db->close_connection();
```

Comment: Hi, i've modified the initial message a bit to clarify the used code. In the added example, if I create a new instance of a class within the while loop $obj_db_insert=new database($query), shouldn't the old connection simply be replaced?